# Sometimes while trying to call the api error showing 'Connection closed before full header was received'

Tags: flutter

In my flutter application error showing as 'Connection closed before full header was received'.
This issue is not happening always, most of the time webservice works but some times it is showing that 'Connection closed before full header was received'.

Am checking in my real device.
For webservices am using http: ^0.13.4.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: try to update the package: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: Did you solve the problem?